# Angular 5 Reactive Forms, Add debounce time to FormControl inside FormArray

Tags: angular5, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I've a formArray named invites,

```
this.userInviteForm = this.fb.group({
  invites: this.fb.array([ this.buildInvite() ])
});

buildInvite(): FormGroup {
return this.fb.group({
  userIdentifier: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EMAILPHONE_REGEX)]],
  roleId: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

}

how to add debounce time to `userIdentifier` field of invites array so that the user have some time before pattern validation error kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating the same issue and found that with angular 6.1.0 I didn't need the debouncer, please take a look on this implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-playground?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You will see that the validation happens, but the state is not invalid.